# Laravel (OctoberCMS) sorting (getting) models

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to sort lessons by group name (in component). I take group_id by Post method using Ajax and trying to get similar lessons, but the returned array is empty.

Schedule.php:

```
        public $belongsTo = [
            'discipline' => 'Titamik\Cio\Models\Discipline',
            'auditorium' => 'Titamik\Cio\Models\Auditorium',
            'professors' => 'Titamik\Cio\Models\Professor',
            'groups'     => 'Titamik\Cio\Models\Group',
        ];
```

Group.php:

```
        public $hasMany = [
                'direction' => 'Titamik\Cio\Models\Direction',
                'schedule' => 'Titamik\Cio\Models\Schedule'
        ];
```

ScheduleComponent.php:

```
        public function onSort() {
            $groupId = post('groupid');
            $this->page['schedule'] = Schedule::groups()->where('id', $groupId)->get();
            return $this->page['schedule'];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue. [Read more here](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#querying-relations)

```
$schedules = Schedule::whereHas('groups', function ($query) use ($groupId) {
    $query->where('id', $groupId);
})->get();
```

Another side note. If you are going to sort via ajax don't need a page variable; it won't update without a page load. Just return the values in this case the schedules. I would also look into return [responses](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/response-view#basic-responses) to your requests.

```
public function onSort() {
    $groupId = post('groupid');
    $schedules = Schedule::whereHas('groups', function ($query) use ($groupId) {
        $query->where('id', $groupId);
    })->get();
    return $schedules;
}
```

Comment: Since there will be a lot of sorting, I decided that it is not necessary to make queries to the database every time, but to sort the array that we get when starting the component. In this regard, there are three questions:
1. is This the right decision?
2. How do I get the id of the group associated with the lesson ```$this->page['schedule'][1]->groups[0]```
3. Why is it more rational to use an array via return, rather than page variable, if I use the update parameter
``` update: {'schedulecomponent::schedule-table': '#schedule-table-container'},```

Comment: @Titamik You never explained that you were updating a partial. Open up a new question for your 2nd and 3rd question. Your first question is an opinion and if you are strictly looking for performance get a better server. Laravel is pretty efficient at querying a database. I have not had a performance issue with lots of filters.